# z-index doesn't work in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, z-index

first of all, i'm using [this responsive template](https://themewagon.com/themes/white-pro-free-creative-multipurpose-html5-template/) for creating a website.
When you scroll down to the footer, the navbar on top is above the content, so you can see the navbar all the time. But when you reach the footer, the footer just overlaps the navbar. It seems, that the z-index attribute doesn't take effect. This bug is only in Safari. You can reproduce it, when your resolution is something like a mobile resolution (portrait).

[ONLY in SAFARI], this error doesnt appear in Chrome or Firefox

I really don't know what to do, i already tried a few things, which didnt solve the problem.

Please help :) Thx

Edit:

The Navbar is implemented as followed in index.html

```
<!-- PAGE -->
<div id="page">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <header>

        <!-- MENU BLOCK -->
        <div class="menu_block">

            <!-- CONTAINER -->
            <div class="container clearfix">

                <!-- LOGO -->
                <div class="logo pull-left">
                    <a href="index.html" ><span class="b1">w</span><span class="b2">h</span><span class="b3">i</span><span class="b4">t</span><span class="b5">e</span></a>
                </div><!-- //LOGO -->

                <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
                <div id="search-form" class="pull-right">
                    <form method="get" action="#">
                        <input type="text" name="Search" value="Search" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Search';" />
                    </form>
                </div><!-- SEARCH FORM -->

                <!-- MENU -->
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <nav class="navmenu center">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="first active scroll_btn"><a href="#home" >Home</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#about" >About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#projects" >Projects</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#team" >Team</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="#news" >News</a></li>
                            <li class="scroll_btn last"><a href="#contacts" >Contacts</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-menu">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" >Pages</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="blog.html" >Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog-post.html" >Blog Post</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="portfolio-post.html" >Portfolio Single Work</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- //MENU -->
            </div><!-- //MENU BLOCK -->
        </div><!-- //CONTAINER -->
    </header><!-- //HEADER -->
```

The Footer is implemented in index.html

```
    <!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>

    <!-- CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- ROW -->
        <div class="row" data-appear-top-offset="-200" data-animated="fadeInUp">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 padbot30">
                <h4><b>Featured</b> posts</h4>
                <div class="recent_posts_small clearfix">
                    <div class="post_item_img_small">
                        <img src="images/blog/1.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_item_content_small">
                        <a class="title" href="blog.html" >As we have developed a unique layout template</a>
                        <ul class="post_item_inf_small">
                            <li>10 January 2014</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="recent_posts_small clearfix">
                    <div class="post_item_img_small">
                        <img src="images/blog/2.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_item_content_small">
                        <a class="title" href="blog.html" >How much is to develop a design for the game?</a>
                        <ul class="post_item_inf_small">
                            <li>14 January 2014</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="recent_posts_small clearfix">
                    <div class="post_item_img_small">
                        <img src="images/blog/3.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_item_content_small">
                        <a class="title" href="blog.html" >How to pump designer</a>
                        <ul class="post_item_inf_small">
                            <li>21 December 2013</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 padbot30 foot_about_block">
                <h4><b>About</b> us</h4>
                <p>We value people over profits, quality over quantity, and keeping it real. As such, we deliver an unmatched working relationship with our clients.</p>
                <p>Our team is intentionally small, eclectic, and skilled; with our in-house expertise, we provide sharp and</p>
                <ul class="social">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="map_show fa fa-map-marker"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="respond_clear"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 padbot30">
                <h4><b>Contacts</b> Us</h4>

                <!-- CONTACT FORM -->
                <div class="span9 contact_form">
                    <div id="note"></div>
                    <div id="fields">
                        <form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix" action="#">
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="Name" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Name') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Name';" />
                            <textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';">Message</textarea>
                            <input class="contact_btn" type="submit" value="Send message" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- //CONTACT FORM -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- //ROW -->
    </div><!-- //CONTAINER -->
</footer><!-- //FOOTER -->
```

The style.css implements following styles to the elements:

Footer:

```
footer {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:60px 0 10px;
  color:#999;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index:1;
}
```

Menu_block:

```
.menu_block {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:9999;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:80px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Comment: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)  No, please create a [MCVE]

Comment: added some information. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

it disappears because you set `#slidebox` to `display: none;` in your min style. Just remove the `display: none;`

Comment: what do you mean? I dont find "#slidebox" ... pls give me some more information

Comment: i cannot imagine that your post is the solution, but i really would love to simply try it. Pls give me more information i.e. code line, file name, etc.

Comment: @Jones sry thought the link you posted was your website. Really sorry about that. I just realized its a template download.

Comment: no problem man. I would appreciate if you try to help me :) ... the link i posted above is the template i used. But i didn't change much. The problem I discribed is already implemented in the template :/ So the programmer of the template didn't realize or didn't solve the problem as well

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using z-index on the navbar and the footer ? It should do the business normally in every browser.

Make sure the value of the footer is lower than the navbar at all time.

Comment: Yes of course i tried it. I edited the post with some code. It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari